# How to limit decimal precision in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

My SQL query is `"SELECT productid,FORMAT(AVG(score),2) FROM product GROUP BY productid"`

I am getting **output** as

`1001 : 2.23,
1002 : -2.69`

In Hibernate my query will be `"SELECT product.productId,FORMAT(AVG(product.score),2) FROM ProductDAO product GROUP BY product.productId"`

But the **format function** not supported in hibernate, is there any way to achieve decimal precision in hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hibernate you can achieve the decimal precision by specifying the 
precision & scale property in hbm mapping.

But in your case as you are using AVG function, hence above approach will not work.
You can collect the value of AVG(score) in BigDecimal & use setScale method of the BigDecimal.

```
 aNumber.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```